# finding the coordinate given a distance with its coordinates

Tags: analytic-geometry

A point $P(x,y)$ has a distance $5\sqrt{2}$ units from $Q(4, -7)$ and a distance $\sqrt{106}$ units from $R(-6,5)$. Knowing that, find $P$.

[the image is exactly the set of problem that our professor given to us](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw71O.jpg)

I assume that the 3 problems are somewhat related, and the only formula that she taught us is the  distance formula, which is $D =\sqrt{(x_2−x)^2+(y_2−y)^2}$

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: find the coordinates of the P

Comment: So, you need to write down two times the distance formula

Comment: plss  help me i been solving this problem for about 3 hours, and still i can't find the solution.

Comment: how can you show me an example :)

Comment: plss even a link on how to do it

Comment: Please wait, I am solving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sqrt{(x_p-4)^2+(y_p+7)^2}=5\sqrt{2}$$
$$\sqrt{(x_p+6)^2+(y_p-5)^2}=\sqrt{106}$$

Here, we do:

$${(x_p-4)^2+(y_p+7)^2}=50$$
$${(x_p+6)^2+(y_p-5)^2}=106$$

Now we, expand above two formulas (for simplicity, i use x and y):

$$x^2 -8x+16+y^2+14y+49=50$$
$$x^2+12x+36+y^2-10y+25=106$$

Some modification,
$$x^2+y^2-8x+14y=-15 \ \ \ \ (I)$$
$$x^2+y^2+12x-10y=40 \ \ \  \ (II)$$

here, we multiplie them by $-1$ then summation, we get:

$$20x+-24y=65$$

therfore, we have:

$$x=\frac{65+24y}{20} \ \ \ \ \ (**)$$

by putting (**) in (I) or (II), you can calculate the possible answers

Comment: i actually already do that but i dont know what will i do next

Comment: ok got it, but by that how can i find the coordinates

Comment: thanks for this, you're an angel :)

Comment: @justine UW, by the way, next time, in the question show what you have done so far. Since this type questions usually attract downvotes.

Comment: yeah noted..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Notice, distance between $P(x, y)$ & $Q(4, -7)$ is $5\sqrt 2$ hence, $$\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-(-7))^2}=5\sqrt 2$$
$$x^2+y^2-8x+14y+15=0\tag 1$$
distance between $P(x, y)$ & $R(-6, 5)$ is $\sqrt {106}$ hence, $$\sqrt{(x-(-6))^2+(y-5)^2}=\sqrt {106}$$
$$x^2+y^2+12x-10y-45=0\tag 2$$
subtracting (1) from (2), one should get
$$20x-24y-60=0$$$$\implies y=\frac{5x-15}{6}\tag 3$$
setting the value of $y$ in (1), one should get 
$$x^2+\left(\frac{5x-15}{6}\right)^2-8x+14\left(\frac{5x-15}{6}\right)+15=0$$
$$61x^2+18x-720=0$$
$$x=\frac{-9\pm \sqrt{44001}}{61}$$
now, set the values of $x$ in (3), find corresponding values of $y$

> **Note:** There are two points $P(x, y) $ lying either side of the line $QR$ joining the points $Q(4, 7)$ & $R(-6, 5)$.